# Angular Material Toogle Buttons with unwanted marks after minor update

Tags: angular, angular-material

I updated my Angular Material from 17.0 to 17.3 (only a minor update) and suddenly there are some hook/checkmarks in the mat-button-toggle buttons.

```
<mat-button-toggle class="btn-primary" [checked]="this.settings.value1===0" (click)="this.settings.value1=0">MyLabel</mat-button-toggle>
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

In the documentation is no hint, how to remove these marks and restore the old style/behavior.
How can I remove them or do I have to change the whole component and look for something else, if I don't want this marks?

Comment: which version you migrate from ?

Comment: I updated from 17.0 to 17.3